# Installing wifi network adapter

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi

I am new to Raspberry Pi. I have a **headless Pi** running **noobs** on it.
The Pi is connected to a router via an  ethernet cable and I am ssh'ing into it via wi-fi from a PC.

I am following this tutorial: [How to Setup Wi-Fi On Your Raspberry Pi via the Command Line](http://www.howtogeek.com/167425/how-to-setup-wi-fi-on-your-raspberry-pi-via-the-command-line/)

However, I think my Pi's interface file is different than it's mentioned in this tutorial. I tried to mess around but then, even my ethernet connection breaks and I have to reinstall the entire operating system on Pi.

Here's the link for the [file containing links of all the snapshots](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxuPEVNjHFQkTFRXajRDOFZiQ0k/view?usp=sharing), which you may require.

Please help me out with the correct configurations I need to make in the interface file.

P.S.
I am absolute novice, **I don't know about networking (Just started working on this kinda stuff)**. So it would be great if you clearly mention the correct configuration in answer **plus changes I have to make in `wpa_supplicant.conf`**

I've tried my best to make question thorough.

Sorry, I had to mention links in other file, They didn't let me post more than two links at a time.

Thanks a lot for your hardwork in solving this problem in advance..!

**EDIT 1**

The links to screen snapshots might not be working before, now the link file contains updated links, which point directly to images.

**EDIT 2**

I haven't changed any content of any file, I have reinstalled the operating system. I just wanted to know what's the problem.

- **Could this problem be caused by missing drivers ?**

It does not automatically install the wi-fi adapter although I can see it in `dmesg` as being detected as a `wlan` device.

Comment: The default Raspbian desktop has a wifi set up button.  Why did that not work?  Perhaps your model of dongle is not supported.  Have you googled for your dongle and Raspberry Pi?

Comment: No i guess there's not any "wifi-config" icon

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Raspbian released in May 2015 changed the way WiFi works. This makes all the existing tutorials obsolete.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/README.md should work, but assumes you have a monitor. I suggest you borrow one to setup.

Setting up `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` as described may work IF YOU HAVEN'T ALREADY CHANGED `/etc/network/interfaces` following the existing tutorials.

Comment: It doesn't shows any wireless network adapter, this is what i am trying to do. I mentioned the link to the adapter i've been using. It says it's linux compatible though.

Comment: Whatever "it" is you haven't given us any detail. What are you trying? What have you changed? You have given no detail of what version you are using, and you seem reluctant to tell us what adapter. What does `lsusb` show?

Comment: well most of the information is in the link file i shared above, and here's "lsusb" 
http://imgur.com/9EIyaIn
and "It" is raspbian, I am sorry of not being enough clear.
Here's the link of adapter I am using http://imgur.com/FtkBmb7
(Seller mentions that this adapter works with raspberri Pi)
Please refer the link file i've shared in question it may contain some information, you might need :)

Comment: And the raspbean version is I thing 14.1 , file says Noobs V1_4_1
and pi is 
raspberry pi 2 model B

Comment: There is no 14.1 `uname -v` will show details. No the link does not SHOW WHAT YOU DID. In more than 40 years of engineering, I have discovered that people DO NOT follow instructions. You may or may not have followed these. If you want further help post the contents of files you changed NOT links to external sites.

Comment: Okay so here's what I did, Since I've been using pi headless, I had to install using 'silentinstall' which is through adding "silentinstall" in recovery.cmdline in pi's os file. I also Edited file "Flavours.json" in that i had to remove "raspbean boot to scratch part". I also had to remove all folders except raspbean, That's what i had to do to silentinstall the operating system ON PI. Now then I tried different guides over internet to setup the wifi adapter. It didn't worked now I have reinstalled the fresh copy of operating system and it's running fine...I already mentioned what lsusb shows.

Comment: uname -v shows 
#781 SMP PREEMPT TUE APR 21 18:07:59 BST 2015
and all the links that i've mentioned is the snapshots of what i am getting on screen.They are not from external sites, I have just uploaded them on external sites

Comment: The links i've posted earlier might not be working, now i've updated links, They should work, If not please notify me.

Comment: The normal practice on this site is to post TEXT. You should also update your original question, NOT add comments. I did look at one of your links, and I find it illegible. You still haven't posted the contents of files you changed.